# No interactions wanted here exception

Tags: spring, testing, junit, controller, mockito

i'm writing test for my Spring MVC Controller. 
I get  a org.Mockito.exception.verifications.NoInteractionWanted exception, with this stack trace:

> No interactions wanted here:
>   -> at com.test.TestInsertUtente.testInserimentoUtente(TestInsertUtente.java:124)
>   But found this interaction:
>   -> at com.test.UtenteForm.insertUtente(UtenteForm.java:149)

Why?

---

```
public class TestInsertUtente {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Mock
private UtenteService utenteService;

@InjectMocks
private UtenteForm utenteForm;

@Before
public void setUp() {

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    when(utenteService.insertUtente(isA(Utente.class))).thenReturn(new Utente("utente.test","utente","test","utente@test.com","test",0));

    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(utenteForm).build();
}

@Test
public void testInserimentoUtente() throws Exception {

    mockMvc.perform(post("/all/utente/form/insert/${action}","resta")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
            .param("utente", "utente.test")
            .param("nome", "utente1")
            .param("cognome", "test")
            .param("email", "utente@test.com")
            .param("password", "test")
            .param("statoRecord", "0")
            .sessionAttr("utente", new Utente())
    ).andExpect(status().isMovedTemporarily())
    .andExpect(view().name("redirect:/web/all/utente/form/utente.test/modifica"))
    .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/web/all/utente/form/utente.test/modifica?insert=true"))
    .andExpect(model().size(2))
    .andExpect(model().attribute("insert", equalTo(true)));

    ArgumentCaptor<Utente> formObjectArgument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Utente.class);
    verify(utenteService, times(1)).insertUtente(formObjectArgument.capture());
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(utenteService);

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell why this ...

```
verifyNoMoreInteractions(utenteService);
```

... fails because we cannot see (a) the rest of your test case and (b) your controller code. Perhaps your controller invokes that method twice?

However, there are a few other aspects of your test which could be cleaned up and these changes might make `verifyNoMoreInteractions` redundant.

Your test uses both `when` and `verify` for the same call: `utenteService.insertUtente()`

In your `setUp()` you tell Mockito to return `new Utente("utente.test","utente","test","utente@test.com","test",0)` when it is invoked with **any** instance of `Utente`. However you do not make use of this expectation i.e. you do not assert that this Utente instance is returned or otherwise used in your controller.

Then, in `testInserimentoUtente()` you verify that `utenteService.insertUtente()` is invoked and you capture the argument passed in that invocation but you don't make any assertions on that captured argument.

I would suggest that should have either the `when` expectation or the `verify` assertion depending on what your controller does with the repsonse from `utenteService.insertUtente()` however you do not need **both** the `when` expectation and the `verify` assertion. If you establish your expectations of `utenteService.insertUtente()` clearly then I suspect the call to `verifyNoMoreInteractions` will no longer be required.

Comment: Thanks, the error goes away by adding verify afterwards. Pretty terrible imo. You could look for hours for this problem. Sometimes I just want a mock to return something, the test framework shouldn't decide for me  what I need to verify. It doesn't tell you what the problem is either. In other words, makes zero sense and it makes me want to slap the developer who implements this kind of api for the time wasted.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue.  In my case, I was trying to mock an `EmailService`.  After mocking the email sending part and adding `Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(emailService)`.  I got exception `No interactions wanted here`.

After debugging figured that the message printed in the exception is wrong, but there were interactions.  In my case, `EmailService` had 3 methods, 2 `public` and 1 `private`.  The test case was trying to `ArgumentCapture` the `public` method and `verify` it.  The `public` method called on `EmailService` was internally making a call to a `private` method.  I figured this out by adding a `breakpoint` to `NoMoreInteractions.java::verify()` of `MockitoLibrary`.

The `breakpoint` revealed that there were 2 `interactions` with the `public` method and 2 `interactions` with the `private` method.  To make the test pass with `Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(emailService)`, I did the following 2 changes.

- Change the private method to public
- add `verify(emailService,times(2)).publicTurnedPrivateMethod()` verification.

Wit this the tests passed.  Hope it helps others

I'm using `MockitoLibrary-2.23.4` and `jUnit-4.12` library.  Not sure if this issue is fixed in the latest versions of the `mockito` library.